# Having two countdown tickers on same web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ticker

I have a working countdown ticker on my page that utilizes javascript (I found a template/did not write the code myself). I have it positioned in a way that looks good on medium to large displays, however I am trying to have it display properly in a mobile size display. I figured a good way to do this would be to create a second identical ticker and place it correctly for the mobile size display and use bootstrap classes to hide/show the tickers when necessary. When the page loads, however the ticker on the large display is working but when i shrink the window to the small size the second ticker will show up properly but the javascript and functionality does not work/the images for the numbers won't display. Maybe I could use one ticker that can somehow change position for the mobile screen size as an alternative?

Here is the code for the working ticker:

There is a body onload function:

```
 <body onload="countdown(year,month,day,hour,minute)">
```

Here is the code adding the ticker to the body of the page:

```
<div id="holder" class="hidden-xs">
<div id="timer">
    <div id="note"></div>
    <div id="countdown">
        <img height=21 src="digital-numbers/bkgd.gif" width=16 name="day1">
        <img height=21 src="digital-numbers/bkgd.gif" width=16 name="day2">
        <img height=21 src="digital-numbers/bkgd.gif" width=16 name="day3">
        <img height=21 id="colon1" src="digital-numbers/colon.png" width=9 name="d1">
        <img height=21 src="digital-numbers/bkgd.gif" width=16 name="h1">
        <img height=21 src="digital-numbers/bkgd.gif" width=16 name="h2">
        <img height=21 id="colon2" src="digital-numbers/colon.png" width=9 name="g1">
        <img height=21 src="digital-numbers/bkgd.gif" width=16 name="m1">
        <img height=21 src="digital-numbers/bkgd.gif" width=16 name="m2">
        <img height=21 id="colon3" src="digital-numbers/colon.png" width=9 name="j1">
        <img height=21 src="digital-numbers/bkgd.gif" width=16 name="s1">
        <img height=21 src="digital-numbers/bkgd.gif" width=16 name="s2">
        <div id="title">
            <div class="title" style="position: absolute; top: 36px; left: 42px">DAYS</div>
            <div class="title" style="position: absolute; top: 36px; left: 105px">HRS</div>
            <div class="title" style="position: absolute; top: 36px; left: 156px">MIN</div>
            <div class="title" style="position: absolute; top: 36px; left: 211px">SEC</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
/*
Count down until any date script-
By JavaScript Kit (www.javascriptkit.com)
Over 200+ free scripts here!
Modified by Robert M. Kuhnhenn, D.O. 
(www.rmkwebdesign.com/Countdown_Timers/)
on 5/30/2006 to count down to a specific date AND time,
on 10/20/2007 to a new format, on 1/10/2010 to include
time zone offset, and on 7/12/2012 to digital numbers.
*/

/*  
CHANGE THE ITEMS BELOW TO CREATE YOUR COUNTDOWN TARGET DATE AND            ANNOUNCEMENT 
ONCE THE TARGET DATE AND TIME ARE REACHED.
*/
var note="Warrior Games 2015 Have Arrived!";    /* -->Enter what you    want the script to 
                  display when the target date and time 
                  are reached, limit to 25 characters */
var year=2015;      /* -->Enter the count down target date YEAR */
var month=06;       /* -->Enter the count down target date MONTH */
var day=19;         /* -->Enter the count down target date DAY */
var hour=0;         /* -->Enter the count down target date HOUR (24 hour     clock) */
var minute=0;      /* -->Enter the count down target date MINUTE */
var tz=-4;          /* -->Offset for your timezone in hours from UTC (see 
          http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/index.htm to find 
          the timezone offset for your location) */

//-->    DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW!    <--   
d1 = new Image(); d1.src = "digital-numbers/1.png";
d2 = new Image(); d2.src = "digital-numbers/2.png";
d3 = new Image(); d3.src = "digital-numbers/3.png";
d4 = new Image(); d4.src = "digital-numbers/4.png";
d5 = new Image(); d5.src = "digital-numbers/5.png";
d6 = new Image(); d6.src = "digital-numbers/6.png";
d7 = new Image(); d7.src = "digital-numbers/7.png";
d8 = new Image(); d8.src = "digital-numbers/8.png";
d9 = new Image(); d9.src = "digital-numbers/9.png";
d0 = new Image(); d0.src = "digital-numbers/0.png";
bkgd = new Image(); bkgd.src = "digital-numbers/bkgd.gif";

var montharray=new     Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"    );

function countdown(yr,m,d,hr,min){
theyear=yr;themonth=m;theday=d;thehour=hr;theminute=min;
var today=new Date();
var todayy=today.getYear();
if (todayy < 1000) {todayy+=1900;}
var todaym=today.getMonth();
var todayd=today.getDate();
var todayh=today.getHours();
var todaymin=today.getMinutes();
var todaysec=today.getSeconds();
var todaystring1=montharray[todaym]+" "+todayd+", "+todayy+" "+todayh+":"+todaymin+":"+todaysec;
var todaystring=Date.parse(todaystring1)+(tz*1000*60*60);
var futurestring1=(montharray[m-1]+" "+d+", "+yr+" "+hr+":"+min);
var futurestring=Date.parse(futurestring1)-(today.getTimezoneOffset()*(1000*60));
var dd=futurestring-todaystring;
var dday=Math.floor(dd/(60*60*1000*24)*1);
var dhour=Math.floor((dd%(60*60*1000*24))/(60*60*1000)*1);
var dmin=Math.floor(((dd%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))/(60*1000)*1);
var dsec=Math.floor((((dd%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))%(60*1000))/1000*1);
if(dday<=0&&dhour<=0&&dmin<=0&&dsec<=0){
    document.getElementById('note').innerHTML=note;
    document.getElementById('note').style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('countdown').style.display="none";
    clearTimeout(startTimer);
    return;
}
else {
    document.getElementById('note').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('timer').style.display="block";
    startTimer = setTimeout("countdown(theyear,themonth,theday,thehour,theminute)",500);
}
convert(dday,dhour,dmin,dsec);
}

function convert(d,h,m,s) {
if (!document.images) return;
if (d <= 9) {
    document.images.day1.src = bkgd.src;
    document.images.day2.src = bkgd.src;
    document.images.day3.src = eval("d"+d+".src");
}
else if (d <= 99) {
    document.images.day1.src = bkgd.src;
    document.images.day2.src = eval("d"+Math.floor(d/10)+".src");
    document.images.day3.src = eval("d"+(d%10)+".src");
}
else {
    document.images.day1.src = eval("d"+Math.floor(d/100)+".src");
    var day = d.toString();
    day = day.substr(1,1);
    day = parseInt(day);
    document.images.day2.src = eval("d"+day+".src");
    document.images.day3.src = eval("d"+(d%10)+".src");
}
if (h <= 9) {
    document.images.h1.src = d0.src;
    document.images.h2.src = eval("d"+h+".src");
}
else {
    document.images.h1.src = eval("d"+Math.floor(h/10)+".src");
    document.images.h2.src = eval("d"+(h%10)+".src");
}
if (m <= 9) {
    document.images.m1.src = d0.src;
    document.images.m2.src = eval("d"+m+".src");
}
else {
    document.images.m1.src = eval("d"+Math.floor(m/10)+".src");
    document.images.m2.src = eval("d"+(m%10)+".src");
}
if (s <= 9) {
    document.images.s1.src = d0.src;
    document.images.s2.src = eval("d"+s+".src");
}
else {
    document.images.s1.src = eval("d"+Math.floor(s/10)+".src");
    document.images.s2.src = eval("d"+(s%10)+".src");
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have 2 `<div id="countdown">` ?
The code will not work on the second div because the javascript code try to find only the first one of div element with id `countdown`

Comment: No I have a different div for the 2nd ticker

Comment: For another route, would it be possible to just have one ticker but move its position for different screen sizes?

Comment: what is the div id of 2nd ticker?